# SQL:Missing data from set

Tags: sql, if-statement, logic, dynamic-sql

I have a stored procedure which requires a certain set of values (T_id in the following code) to execute properly, all the values must be present in the set (coming from a #temp table). These values come from numerous feeds and at the time of execution  (of the stored procedure) some may not be present. I am attempting to put of a bit of code in place whereby if all values are not present then the stored procedure is not executed. I have stated with:
1) a table for comparison

```
 create table #test(T_id real)
 insert into #test (T_id)
 select id from dbo.mapping
 where id in('1', '2','3','4','5','6')
```

2) (the bit I am struggling with) comparison to what is present against the above table...and avoiding the code being executed. note:assign_ID is a table which may or may not contain all the required values (from the feed).

```
IF NOT EXISTS (select T_id from #assign_ID except select T_id  from  #test) 
Exec [dbo].[storedprocedure]@rdate, '1,2,3,4,5,6,'
else 
print N'missing'
```

I am not 100% sure I have got the logic correct. But, do I need dynamic SQL as the decision to run is made at run time? Not sure. Please, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change the query, maybe the command NOT EXISTS is not working with the IF command. Try to use WHERE and execute that block.

Comment: Sorry, make no difference....is the logic correct...not sure. I think IF NOT EXISTS is pretty common, why would it not work?

Comment: Pretty sure it is a syntax error. I don't find anything wrong with your logic. Try to add a bracket after IF because that's how IF conditions usually start. Like if( a>b) and so on. So try to write IF ( NOT EXISTS(........))